# Why is my Replace() method not working correctly?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a `UserForm` that contains a series of `CheckBoxes`, `TextBoxes`, and `Buttons`. One `TextBox` asks the user for a specific date, and once the `OKButton` is clicked, it takes the and checks the user's formatting of the date. I have used a `Select/Case` to check the different formats the user inputs and converts them to a specific format for file-name purposes (this macro takes the user's selected file-paths and generates an report, saving it as `[MM-DD-YY] Balance Report.xlsx`)

My select case checks if the user's input is formatted as MMDDYYYY, MMDDYY, MM/DD/YYYY, MM/DD/YY, MM-DD-YYYY, MM-DD-YYYY.

The code is as follows:

```
Function PostDateBoolean() As Boolean

    PostingDate = PostDateTextBox.Value 'tested as 071616       (07-16-2016)

    Select Case True
        Case Is = PostingDate Like "##/##/##" Or _
            PostingDate Like "##-##-##" Or _
            PostingDate Like "##/##/20##" Or _
            PostingDate Like "##-##-20##" Or _
            PostingDate Like "######" Or _
            PostingDate Like "########"

            PostDateBoolean = True
        Select Case True
            Case Is = PostingDate Like "##/##/##" Or _
                PostingDate Like "##-##-##"
                PostingDate = Replace(PostingDate, Right(PostingDate, 2), _
                "20" & Right(PostingDate, 2))
                PostDateTextBox.Value = PostingDate
        End Select
        Select Case True
            Case Is = PostingDate Like "######"
                ' THE ERROR IS HERE VVVV
            PostingDate = Replace(PostingDate, Right(PostingDate, 2), _
                    "/20" & Right(PostingDate, 2))
                PostingDate = Replace(PostingDate, Right(PostingDate, 7), _
                    "/" & Right(PostingDate, 7))
                PostDateTextBox.Value = PostingDate
                GoTo CheckDone:
        End Select
        Select Case True
            Case Is = PostingDate Like "########"
                PostingDate = Replace(PostingDate, Right(PostingDate, 4), _
                    "/" & Right(PostingDate, 4))
                PostingDate = Replace(PostingDate, Right(PostingDate, 7), _
                    "/" & Right(PostingDate, 7))
                PostDateTextBox.Value = PostingDate
                GoTo CheckDone:
        End Select
CheckDone:
        Case Else
            msg = "Please Enter a Date in the correct Date Format:" & vbCr _
            & "MM/DD/YYYY Or MM/DD/YY"
        PostDateBoolean = False
    End Select
    PostDateFileName = PostingDate
    PostDateFileName = Replace(PostDateFileName, Right(PostDateFileName, 5), _
                "-" & Right(PostDateFileName, 4))
    PostDateFileName = Replace(PostDateFileName, Right(PostDateFileName, 8), _
                "-" & Right(PostDateFileName, 7))

End Function
```

After my line

`PostingDate = Replace(PostingDate, Right(PostingDate, 2), "/20" & Right(PostingDate, 2))`

The value of Posting date goes from `071616` to `07/2016/2016`. My intent by the above line of code is to replace the last two digits in `071616` and replace it with `/2016`. For some reason it's replacing the 4 digits rather than just the two digits. I assume the issue for this is that in the second parameter for `Replace ( string1, find, replacement, [start, [count, [compare]]] )` [Find as String], it finds all values (`16`) in the string and replaces it with `/2016`. Is there a better way to get JUST the last two characters and replace them, rather than all `16's` in the string?

Comment: I'd suggest a completely different approach - instead of trying to validate whatever garbage ends up in the `TextBox`, why don't you just use the `TextBox` events to enforce an input mask?

Comment: `it finds all values (16) in the string and replaces it with /2016` - yes, that's exactly what it is supposed to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use `Replace` when you don't know where the match is.
You use something else (`Left`, `Right`, `Mid`) when you know exactly which characters you are replacing.

```
PostingDate = Left$(PostingDate, Len(PostingDate) - 2) & "/20" & Right$(PostingDate, 2)
```

However a better approach would be to, once you have detected in which format your date is, convert it to an actual `Date` and then `Format$()` it to whatever format you like.

Answer (score 2):

*This isn't an "answer" to your question, but it was just too long to include as a comment.*

In addition to what GSerg said, your Select Case statement should probably be rewritten to something like:

```
    PostDateBoolean = True

    Select Case True
        Case PostingDate Like "##/##/##",
             PostingDate Like "##-##-##"

            PostingDate = Left$(PostingDate, 6) & _
                          "20" & Right$(PostingDate, 2)
            PostDateTextBox.Value = PostingDate

        Case PostingDate Like "##/##/20##",
             PostingDate Like "##-##-20##"

        Case PostingDate Like "######"

            PostingDate = Left$(PostingDate, 2) & "/" & _
                          Mid$(PostingDate, 3, 2) & "/" & _
                          "20" & Right$(PostingDate, 2)
            PostDateTextBox.Value = PostingDate

        Case PostingDate Like "########"

            PostingDate = Left$(PostingDate, 2) & "/" & _
                          Mid$(PostingDate, 3, 2) & "/" & _
                          Right$(PostingDate, 4)
            PostDateTextBox.Value = PostingDate

        Case Else
            msg = "Please Enter a Date in the correct Date Format:" & vbCr _
            & "MM/DD/YYYY Or MM/DD/YY"
            PostDateBoolean = False
    End Select
```

Comment: Along the lines of "Answer" or "Solution," would it be appropriate to mark this as correct? Mostly since my original problem would be a misunderstanding of what method to use (`Replace()` vs `Left()/Right()`) for the best result. This works phenomenal! Thank you!

Comment: @Munkeeface - I would suggest that the answer supplied by GSerg should be marked as the solution.  That was the answer that explained the difference between Replace and Mid/Left/Right.  My "answer" only went on to explain how you should really be writing your Select Case statements, which possibly fixed up a few other issues you were having, or going to have.